# Pass MVC Controller a list of columns and return data for those columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am trying to build a helper class for [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) and need some advice.

I want to create a helper that I can pass in an object that represents the settings for a `DataTables` that is typed by a specific model. This object would contain a collection of expressions that represent the columns to be used by the helper. As part of the `DataTables` object there will be a property that holds the URL that servers up the data for the grid. This will effectively be the `sAjaxSource` parameter. As part of the URL call, a JSON package will be sent that will contains the information about the columns. This whole section, I understand how to build. Basically, I would build out the `DataTables` JavaScript code including column definitions and create a JSON object that represents the columns I want to pass in the URL.

The area I needs some advice on is building the data for the specific columns once hte call is made to the server / controller. So my controller may look like this:

```
public ActionResult GetUsersList(IEnumerable<DatatableColumnJson> columns)
    {
        var users = _someUserRepository.GetAll();


        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            //Here I would build the JSON that DataTables needs to render the grid.
            //I would iterate through the users and pull out the data for the specific columns
        }

        return Json(someCompleteDataTablesObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Supporting Classes:

```
public class DatatableColumnJson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Visible { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

So I first thought I could use reflection, but that seems to be a little intensive, maybe. Another thought was to transform the column names into expressions to possibly pull out the data. I want something efficient and that doesn't have a lot of overhead, but maybe I am asking too much.

Comment: Passing your table columns in plain text across HTTP is a really, really bad idea. It's begging for a SQL injection attack, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Passing columns on the wire should be considered only for apps using read-only database users with strict table access permissions.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with that, because this is only for displaying records and not querying them. Also, the column names could be encoded and passed into the controller. If you notice in my example, the repository is queried before the columns are used.

Comment: I understand the concerns, but this is not answering my question.

Comment: your still exposing your underlying data layer to everyone. Even if they can't use a SQL injection in this instance, your exposing far too much information to anybody wishing to be malicious. Nobody thinks these rules apply to them until the worst happens....

Comment: Again, my question was not around security or best practices. This is a closed system and not used by the public. I don't see how this is relevant right now. If it makes you feel better, let's assume the list of columns is a static list on the server and not passed into the controller.